# A div containing images disappears on iphone

Tags: iphone, html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari

I have tried searching for a solution everywhere but could not find it. Hence posting a request here.

We have a website built on php code-ignition MVC framework, but the issue is with HTML rendering over various devices imo.  a certain section on the bottom of the a rendered page disappears on iphone, it renders fine on ipad and normal browser. I have saved the page as HTML and am able to successfully reproduce it via chrome for devices (from developer tools), by switching over various devices.

The designer who helped create these templates are not accessible anymore, so I am not able to get any further help. I suspect it to be a CSS issue. The website uses twitter-bootstrap.

Screenshots:

Normal Browser & Iphone redering comparison:

[image]

(the div in question is marked by the arrow)

I have looked into the view source and the div in question appears on both versions in the HTML source:

```
<div class="button-holders button-overlay" id="button_holder">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 noway" id="noway" style="display: block;">
        <a id="noway1" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none;"> <img src="./Coupon Crank_files/button.png" width="70" height="70"></a>
        <a id="noway1" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none;" onclick="rotate_crank_coupon_load('1', '0')"> NO WAY</a>
    </div><!--noway-->
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 nah" id="nah" style="display: block;">
        <a id="nah1" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none;"> <img src="./Coupon Crank_files/nah.png" width="70" height="70"></a>
        <a id="nah1" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none;" onclick="rotate_crank_coupon_load('2', '0')"> NAH</a>
    </div><!--noway-->
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 sure" id="sure" style="display: block;">
        <a id="sure1" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none;"> <img src="./Coupon Crank_files/sure.png" width="70" height="70"></a>
        <a id="sure1" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none;" onclick="rotate_crank_coupon_load('3', '0')"> SURE</a>
    </div><!--noway-->
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 ohyeh" id="ohyeh" style="display: block;">
        <a id="ohyeh1" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none;"> <img src="./Coupon Crank_files/heart.png"></a>
        <a id="ohyeh1" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none;" onclick="rotate_crank_coupon_load('4', '0')"> OH YES</a>
    </div><!--noway-->

     <div class="report_abouse_style" id="report_abouse" style="display: block;">             
        <a class="badge badge_edit" id="report_abouse1" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none;"> Report Abuse</a>
    </div>
```

Could it be something that can be fixed via modifying the CSS?

I am attaching the html files to reproduce the issue locally: http://filenurse.com/download/c5d96491585893ee917842a6f11f8166.html

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
AD

Comment: are you using the emulator?

Comment: Yes the above screenshot images are taken on chrome device emulator, but the same behavior happens exactly on an actual iphone device.

Comment: Look inside your media query at 320px see if `.button-holders` `.button-overlay` or  `#button_holder` are set to `display: none;`

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for the tip. I looked into custom.css and could not see them set to display: none for 320px . Infact, it has not been set to display:none over anywhere in the sryle sheet.